# How to fix "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" in Java application running on GKS after certificate expired and was renewed

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, google-kubernetes-engine, keytool, truststore

I’ve been working on a project that uses Java HttpClient on Java 17 to communicate with an api amongst other things.
The project is deployed to GKE and running fine.

Few days ago the client’s SSL certificate expired and I started getting

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
```

more from the stack trace reads:

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434)
... 28 common frames omitted
Causing: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:285)
at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:632)
... 23 common frames omitted
Causing: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:371)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:309)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1277)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1264)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1209)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.lambda$executeTasks$3(SSLFlowDelegate.java:1118)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$DelegatingExecutor.execute(HttpClientImpl.java:157)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.executeTasks(SSLFlowDelegate.java:1113)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.doHandshake(SSLFlowDelegate.java:1079)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.processData(SSLFlowDelegate.java:484)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader$ReaderDownstreamPusher.run(SSLFlowDelegate.java:268)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$LockingRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:205)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:149)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$TryEndDeferredCompleter.complete(SequentialScheduler.java:347)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:151)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:230)
... 3 common frames omitted
Causing: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:578)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:123)
... 12 common frames omitted
Causing: com.libs.card_payment_client.exception.PaymentClientException: Failed to process payment: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryServerCallHandler$UnaryServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:182)
at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:346)
at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:860)
at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
```

This continued even after they renewed their certificate. By the way the certificate is signed by DigiCert Global Root G2

On my local MAC I resolved the issue by downloading the new certificate and using key tool to add it to my trust store using the command.

```
sudo keytool -import -alias qa_interswitch_certificate -file qa.interswitchng.com.cer -keystore /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-17.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
```

However, on redeploying the application to GKE with some other updates, the error doesn’t go away on the remote machine.

I informed our devOps team and they also used keytool to add the new certificate but the error still persists. I'm not much of a devOps guy, but i gave the devOps team the exact command i used to resolve it on my local machine but still getting the same error on the server.

How can I resolve this issue on the remote pods?

Comment: No end-entity cert is ever directly _signed_ by a public root CA like Digicert G2; that's been prohibited for decades. It can very well be _chained under_ that root, and if the server provides the chain/intermediate(s) as required, the Digicert G2 root has been in the default Java truststore since 2016, so it's very unlikely you would ever have needed to add anything anywhere. Unless your code overrides the default, but you'll have to look at the code for that.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 it's issued by Thawte TLS RSA CA G1. Like i mentioned the client's certificate expired and other users complained about the issue. But we were notified that it's now renewed, and i confirmed it is, but my app keeps throwing this error in the cloud deployment env.

Comment: Thawte is one of several brands now owned by Digicert (previously independent then Verisign then Symantec) and as I said Digicert G2 root has been trusted for many years, so it's either the code or (didn't occur to me last time) configuration settings or environment affecting it -- for example if it's Windows and Java is installed under %programfiles*% (as is the Oracle default) data you try to update may disappear due to security features.

Comment: Did you actually rebuild the container image for your app and included the certificate(s) in the trust store for the app in the container image?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085,i was able to add the new certificate on my local machine. the problem is the devOps team deploy the app, after after deployment try to use the keytool to update the key in the pod. but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @GariSingh, the image was rebuilt, deployed and started. Afterwards devOps attempted to use keytool to install the new certificate, which seemed to work without any error, but still Java throws certificate exception shows above.